# i want to give hyperlink to the scanning number,but i dont know how to give

Tags: ionic3

this.barcodeScanner.scan(this.options).then((barcodeData) => {

```
  console.log(barcodeData);
  this.scanDataTrack = barcodeData;
  this.printertrack = barcodeData.text;
  var printertrack=this.printertrack;
    this.printerform.patchValue({ PrinterTrackingNumber: printertrack });
}, (err) => {
  console.log("Error occured : " + err);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide more description about your code.

Comment: @ThanhPhan 
i try to give the link to scanning tracking numbers and redirect to particular websites, like UPS, RedEx, etc. my html code <a (click)="printerTrackingNumberScan()"> <span class="scan-label" > Scan</span> </a>

Comment: when am scanning the numbers it automatically check and redirect to the wedsites, thats it,